# unreported exception ClassNotFoundException;must be caught or declared to be thrown

Tags: java

This is the program I try to compile using jdk."satya" in the program refers to an msaccess db file database.when I try to compile it is showing error like `"MyClass.java:0:error:unreported exception ClassNotFoundException;must be caught or declared to be thrown"`.Even if I change the exception in the program from `SQLException` to Exception it compiles sucessfully.But throwing exception when running the program.How to execute??

```
import java.sql.*;

class MyClass
{
     public static void main(String args[])
     {

      try{ 
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
           Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:satya","","");
           Statement st=con.createStatement();
           ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from studentinfo");
           while(rs.next())
           {
             System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+"\t"+
             rs.getString(2)+"\t"+
             rs.getString(3)+"\t");
           }
         rs.close();
        st.close();

        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
             System.out.println("<P>" + "There was an error doing the query:");
            System.out.println ("<PRE>" + e + "</PRE> \n <P>");
          }
 }
 }
```

Comment: You probably need to add jar with driver class to class path when running your program to eliminate throwing ClassNotFound at runtime

Answer (score 1):

one of your methods throw a `ClassNotFoundException` and you are responsible to deal with those exceptions.
A quickfix

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
```

in this case the exception is printed ot to your console(please expand your question with that output).

Furthermore be sure that you add the jdbc driver library to your project.

Answer (score 0):

`ClassNotFoundException` is a subclass of Exception, that's why you pass compiler. `SQLException` class doesn't wrap `ClassNotFoundException`. Since the `forName()` method of the "`Class`" class is declared as "`throws ClassNotFoundException`", the compiler will require you to wrap the method call with a try/catch block or a `throws` clause on the caller method. The `catch` block must use either a `ClassNotFoundException` or one of its parent `Exception` classes.

You need to figure out the exception throwing at runtime to check why it fails to run ahead.